# returning or redoing the for statement

Tags: java

i want to scan a number from 0 to 100 and when it found a certain number it will execute a function then i want it to return back to the for statement and continue in scanning other numbers.

i have tried changing if statement with while statement but it only repeat the function that are inside the while statement. i want to go back to the for statement to scan the number.

here is an example of what i am trying to do:

```
// returning from if statement back to for statement
for(int number = 0;number < 100;number++){
  if(number == 5){
    // do something

    // come back and keep scanning other number
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Just call a method/function inside the if block or write code in there directly that you wish to execute and you're done. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: As long as you don't break, your loop will continue executing. So just replace `// do something` with whatever call you want.

Comment: You can just insert your function after your if statement. After that function, your for cycle will proceed normally.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to call a function ?

```
// returning from if statement back to for statement
for(int number = 0;number < 100;number++){
  if(number == 5){
    doSomething();

    // come back and keep scanning other number
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform different actions for different numbers:

```
for (int number = 0; number < 100; number++ ) {
    if (number == 5){
        // do something
    } else if (number == 15) {
        // do other thing
    } else if (number == 30) {
        // do yet another thing
    } 
}
```

If you want to perform the same action for different numbers you can use logical OR operator "`||`" - if `number` is equal to any of these values: 5, 10 or 30, code inside curly braces is performed:

```
for (int number = 0;number < 100;number++ ) {
    if (number == 5 || number == 10 || number == 30) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I understood what you are trying to ask. You want to execute a function if you for-loop hits certain numbers. 
I can give you an example for it:

```
public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (i % 25 == 0) {
            exampleFunction();
        }
    }
}

static void exampleFunction() {
    System.out.println("I'm just typing something in the console!");
}
```

}

So what the code does in his main function is searching for numbers that divide with 25 without having a remainder. So for example the numbres 25, 50, 75 and 100.
Everytime it hits one of these numbers the if-clause is true and it will call my exampleFunction(), which prints something out in console. After that it will automatically return to the for loop.

And that's the console output:

```
I'm just typing something in the console!
I'm just typing something in the console!
I'm just typing something in the console!
I'm just typing something in the console!
```

I hope I could help you :)